# Unit test form with ImageField in django

Tags: python, django, python-2.7, unit-testing, django-1.11

I have model with **ImageField**. I am trying to write **unit test** to my form but it always raise error. Can someone say me where is my mistake?

From error I understand that form is not valid. `print str(form.errors)` return me this:

```
<ul class="errorlist"><li>image<ul class="errorlist"><li>This field is required.</li></ul></li></ul>
```

**Error**:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/home/nurzhan/CA/slider/tests.py", in test_form_valid
    self.assertTrue(form.is_valid())
AssertionError: False is not true
```

**tests.py:**

```
def test_form_valid(self):
        self.image_file = open(
            os.path.join(BASE_DIR, 'static/images/test.jpg'), "rb"
        )
        data = {
            'title': 'TEST',
        }
        image_data = {
            'image': self.file_valid
        }
        form = SlideForm(data=data, files=image_data)
        self.assertTrue(form.is_valid())
```

`print data` return me:

`{'image': <open file '/home/nurzhan/CA/static/images/test.jpg', mode 'rb' at 0x7efe24b47b70>}`

Also I tried to use this:

```
data = {
    'image': SimpleUploadedFile(
        self.image_file.name,
        self.image_file.read()
    )
}
```

In this case `print data` return me `{'image': <SimpleUploadedFile: test.jpg (text/plain)>}`

**forms.py**:

```
class ArticleForm(forms.ModelForm):
    class Meta:
    model = Article
    fields = ('image',)

def __init__(self, *args, **kwargs):
    super(SlideForm, self).__init__(*args, **kwargs)
    self.fields['image'].widget.attrs = {
        'accept': 'image/png, image/jpeg, image/gif',
        'id': 'image',
    }
```

**models.py:**

```
from django.db.models.signals import pre_save
from django.dispatch import receiver

class Article(models.Model):
    image = models.ImageField(
        upload_to='article/images/%Y/%m/%d/',
        blank=False,
    )


@receiver(pre_save, sender=Article)
def delete_old_article_image(sender, instance, *args, **kwargs):
    if instance.pk:
        article = article.objects.get(pk=instance.pk)
        if instance.image and article.image != instance.image:
            article.image.delete(False)
```

**ANSWER:**

Corrent unit-test is:

```
  def test_form_valid(self):
        data = {
            'title': 'TEST',
        }
        files_data = {
            'image': SimpleUploadedFile(
                self.image_file.name,
                self.image_valid.read()
            )
        }
        form = ArticleForm(data=data, files=files_data)
        self.assertTrue(form.is_valid())
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I looked up Django's source code and found this:
https://github.com/django/django/blob/master/django/forms/forms.py#L74-L76

You probably need to pass files as `files=data`.

Good luck!

Comment: I fount solution. I use `SimpleUploadedFile` for my image file. Thank you for your answer!